# android block particular website for compiled third party library

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that has this in gradle:

```
compile 'com.thirdparty.library:1.0'
```

What I want is without changing the third party library and only changing my code to block this third party library or my app entirely from accessing a website.
Is it possible?

Note: I don't want to block the device but only my app.

Comment: On Android 7.0+, you might be able to hack a [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html) that is "broken" and prevents anything in your app from accessing that site. The library might be able to bypass this (e.g., work with sockets directly, use `WebView`), and this is not available on older devices. A better solution is to not use this library.

Comment: Needs to work on android 5 and 5.1 only

Comment: Then don't use the library.

Comment: I want to use it and allow it to open any link except one

Comment: Then talk to the developers of the library and convince them to modify it to allow control over this one link.

Comment: The library have a bug and after it opens a specific link my app crashes.

Comment: Then talk to the developers of the library, provide them with a reproducible test case demonstrating the crash, and hope that they fix their bug.

Comment: I already told them about the bug and it is more that a month and i don't think they will do anything about it

Comment: Then don't use the library. Or maintain it yourself.

Comment: I was hopping for an easy solution to block my app from accessing a link but I guess there is none.

Comment: If I use the library I make $1000/month but my app crashes from time to time. What would you do?

Comment: I would ask a separate Stack Overflow question, with a [mcve], showing the complete Java stack trace associated with the crash, along with all of the code associated with the crash, and see if somebody can point out a way to address the crash.